Do they mean the same? "to put oneself ahead vs To put oneself first"
I´d like to know if these two can be used interchangeably.
A. Mark is egotistic. He always puts himself first.
B. Mark is egotistic. He always puts himself ahead.
I´ve heard the first one more and the second one. I´ve heard "ahead" with other nouns, thought, as in "He puts his interests ahead"
Let me know what you think.

I think no native would be likely to use ahead instead of (far more common) first in such contexts specifically in order to convey some subtle difference in meaning. Taking account of  Ngrams not found: always puts his family ahead in this usage chart, I suggest learners just forget about ahead here.

It would have to be "ahead of others".   "ahead" alone doesn't quite convey the idea.

First, I believe you should say egotistical, not egotistic.

A. Mark is egotistical. He always puts himself first.

You don't have to specify what he puts himself first at. It's either handled in the context of the conversation, or you're making a general statement about "everything."
If you want to say that Mark puts himself ahead, you have clarify who he's putting himself ahead of. It can be simple, such as:

Mark is egotistical. He always puts himself ahead of everyone else.
Or
Mark is egotistical. He always puts himself ahead of people with much more talent than he has.


Thanks for your comment. Why do you prefer "egotistical" to "egotistic"? I wasn't able to find the distintion online.

egotistical is far more common. Why do you prefer egotistic?

@StuartF I was going to use "egoist", which sounds closer to my native language, but after checking some dictionaries, they have egotistic and egotistical as other alternatives. Then I read some more online and found out that while "egoist" is reserved more for philosophical discussions, most sites describe the other two as equals.
